# wp_dropdown_nav function to list menu items

Tags: menus, navigation, dropdown

Is there a `wp_dropdown_nav` function to list the menu items in a dropdown the same way as like in `wp_dropdown_categories`.

I need to display a menu when the media size is greater than 480px and dropdown menu if media size is less than 480px.

I am trying to list the menu items as dropdown.

Currently I am using the wp_dropdown_categories instead of navgiation menu items.

Comment: The simple answer is no, there is no such function or action in wordpress. What is it that you want to achieve. I suspect that what you want to do is doable with a custom menu

Comment: I need to switch the menu in case media size is less than 480px.

Comment: @BLPraveen I would recommend [a JavaScript solution](http://css-tricks.com/convert-menu-to-dropdown/).

Comment: No.. I need to display a menu when the media size is greater than  480px and dropdown menu if media size is less than 480px. I am trying to list the menu items as dropdown. Currently I am using the wp_dropdown_categories instead of navgiation menu items.

Comment: Ok, this changes everything. You should include that in your question. As @TheDeadMedic suggested, javascript and media queries should to the trick. Take a look at the twentyfourteen theme included with wordpress. This is beautifully incorporated there. You can also look at the twenty twelve theme.

Comment: I have added it to question